# Connect nodejs to a endpoint status page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm currently making a webpage that will show the status of the endpoints of my api. I have little background in nodejs. The webpage is simply a table that has the endpoint name and shows red/green/yellow box. I had some problems using ajax because of the cross-origin header. I was using the XMLHttpRequest.

Now I will try to do is creating a nodejs server that can fetch this information but I'm having some problems understanding if I need to use express in order to create an app or can I use the 'request' library.

Im kinda confused on how to connect my frontend with a nodejs backend.

Comment: it's also good if you can show us some code so we have an idea what you tried implementing

Answer (score 0):

Typically you connect your front end to a nodejs background the way you connect most client apps to an api, through an Ajax request (XMLHTTPRequest). If you want real-realtime then you would use sockets so you can push updates to the page. If slightly realtime is ok, then you can poll from the client every 5-10 seconds.

You mentioned CORS. If you are trying to access an API that doesn't set cross-origin header, then you proxy requests through your express server since CORS is a browser policy.

Without more information I can't be more specific.